# CMS Error in TYPO3 after restoring backup

Tags: typo3

I have restored a backup from another host and I get the following error on the dashboard:

Oops, an error occurred!
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `uid`, `title` FROM `sys_language` WHERE `sys_language`.`hidden` = 0 ORDER BY `sorting` ASC': Unknown column 'sorting' in 'order clause'

I am new to TYPO3 so unsure where to start with this error. I have searched but not found any relevant answers.

Thanks in advance,
gtg

Comment: you probably have a different version of Typo3 or extensions not installed that were installed on the other version. You need a duplicate of the server files.

Answer (score 2):

The part `[...] Unknown column 'sorting' in 'order clause'` of the error message indicates that a column is missing in database table `sys_language`. As `sys_language` is a system table, I'd first check if the database schema is up-to-date and correct. TYPO3 provides this feature in the "Install Tool".

In the backend of TYPO3 v7/v8, go to **SYSTEM → Install** and open the "Database analyzer" in section "Important actions".

In the backend of TYPO3 v9, go to **ADMIN TOOLS → Maintenance** and execute "Analyze Database Structure".

It is also important to make sure that you are using the same TYPO3 core version as on *the other host*. Assuming you are using TYPO3 v8 (e.g. version 8.7.24) on the original instance and you restore the site on a different server, you should use the same TYPO3 version (or at least the latest version of the 8.7.x branch).

Comment: Thanks, I learnt a lot and did find issues with the database schema. I corrected those in the Database analyzer as suggested. Is there a way to find out which core version of TYPO3 they were using at the previous host as they have not replied to my email request for that info? Also, I now have a new error :"The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured. | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\ServiceUnavailableException thrown in file .../typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php in line 2491."